# Magento 2 : Product attributes color and size Translate issue

Tags: magento2, store-view, translate, inline-translations

[image: Product apge]

It is a Configurable product and the default store view is **Swedish store** and this text ***Color*** and ***size*** need to be translated in  **Swedish** but These words are not translated in Swedish ??

I have tried **Inline translate** but It is not showing the custom text to be added for translation
How can I add a translation for these word **SIZE & COLOR**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the translations per storeview on each attribute option.

You can do this in the Admin "Stores"->"Attributes"->"Products"

Then select the attribute and you can see a matrix of options and storeviews.